# Японські суфікси -сан, -кун, -чян тощо і відмінювання

Tags: відмінювання, іншомовні-слова, суфікси

Намагаюся розібратися з питанням відмінювання японських суфіксів -сан, -кун, -чян і т.д. Жоден із відомих мені правописів не містить бодай натяку на пояснення, як обходитися із цими суфіксами у плані відмінювання.

В Інтернеті знайшов лише одне обговорення цього питання, але воно радше зав'язане на суб'єбктивному сприйнятті - комусь подобається, аби було відмінювання у звертаннях ("Такумі-куне, іди-но сюди"), хтось же проти цього ("Такумі-кун, іди-но сюди").

Ідеться про обговорення тут: http://uanime.org.ua/forum/viewtopic.php?t=524&start=15

Власне, хотів поцікавитися, як буде правильніше з відмінюваннями цих суфіксів, бо наразі виглядає так, що доводиться робити так, як подобається, бо унормування цього питання в офіційних документах, начебто, нема.

Дуже дякую за відповідь.

Comment: Note that these [honorific suffixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_honorifics) in Japanese are generally not gender-specific (although *-chan* is more likely to be used for little girls), but trying to decline female name suffixed with e.g. *-san* using rules of Ukrainian language would sound strange. Even if you drop these suffixes, majority of Japanese names cannot be declined anyway in Ukrainian language...