# Чи потрібно застосовувати кличний відмінок для японських імен, іменних суфіксів?

Tags: власні-назви, відмінювання, іншомовні-слова, іноземні-імена, кличний-відмінок

Є моменти де кличний відмінок підходить до імені, наприклад: Тацуї - Тацує. Але є й імена де він не підходить: Сеіїчі - ?. Також з іменними суфіксами.
І з'являється питання — Чи потрібно застосовувати кличний відмінок для японських імен, іменних суфіксів?

Comment: Коли що, таке питаннє піднімало ся тут:
https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/7305/585

Чомусь не можу позначити як дублікат, але най.